# Rename Multiple Text file using Batch file

Tags: command, dos

How would I write a batch file to rename multiple text files?

Suppose we have to rename 200 files as below

```
ABC_Suman_156smnhk.txt,
ABC_Suman_73564jsdlfm.txt,
ABC_Suman_9864yds7mjf45mj.txt
```

To

```
MNC_Ranj_156smnhk.txt,
MNC_Ranj_73564jsdlfm.txt,
MNC_Ranj_9864yds7mjf45mj.txt
```

Note: I need this `ABC_Suman` part only changed to `MNC_Ranj`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a batch rename, the basic command looks like this:

for filename in *foo*; do echo mv \"$filename\" \"${filename//foo/bar}\"; done > rename.txt
The command works as follows:

The for loop goes through all files with name *foo* in the current directory.
For each filename, it constructs and echoes a command of the form mv “filename” “newfilename”, where the filename and new file name are surrounded by double quotes (to account for spaces in the file name) and the new file name has all instances of foo replaced with bar. The substitution function ${filename//foo/bar} has two slashes (//) to replace every occurrence of foo with bar.
Finally, the entire output is saved to rename.txt for user review to ensure that the rename commands are being generated correctly.

i took it from the following link:
http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/shellscripting/batch_rename

Comment: I have used the below code..and it worked for when file name has single underscore"_"


@echo off -@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions -For /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%I IN ('dir /a-d /b *.gtm') DO rename "%%~I_%%~J" "ManiTh_%%~J"

Comment: Please let me know when the Text file contains two underscore as example ABC_Suman_156smnhk.txt to MNC_Ranj_156smnhk.txt

Answer (score 0):

@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (ABC_Suman*.txt) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  ren "!name!" "!name:ABC_Suman=MNC_Ranj!"
)